# Condition rendering failing in React Native Redux App

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation-v5, conditional-rendering

I'm trying to conditionally render my redux app based on if the user is logged in. The relevant & condensed version of my code is below:

```
let isLoggedIn = false;

export default function App() {
  console.log('App executing...');
  console.log('isLoggedIn: ', isLoggedIn);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {isLoggedIn ? ContactsTab() : Login()}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}

store.subscribe(() => {
  // Set isLoggedIn to true if token is received and reinvoke App()
  if (store.getState().user.token) {
    isLoggedIn = true;
    App();
  }
});
```

The app starts with console logging **isLoggedIn: false** and displaying **Login()**(as expected). When I login on my phone using the correct credentials, **App()** is re-invoked console logging **isLoggedIn: true**(as expected) but it's still displaying **Login()**. If I set **isLoggedIn = true** inside the app function, the app successfully starts displaying the **ContactsTab()**.

What is happening here? Why is my app not moving to **ContactsTab()** when the value of **isLoggedIn** successfully changes to **true**? How can I fix this?

Thank you for reading along. I have been trying to debug this for the past 2 days with no success so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use useState here like this, the useState will automatically renders when the state changes

```
export default function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  console.log('App Executing...');
  console.log('isLoggedIn: ', isLoggedIn);
  store.subscribe(() => {
    // Set isLoggedIn to true if token is received and reinvoke App()
    if (store.getState().user.token) {
      setLoggedIn(true);
    }
  });
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {isLoggedIn ? ContactsTab() : Login()}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow! That works. Only change I needed to make was subscribing to the store inside my App(). If it's okay, I'll edit your code a bit to a version that fixed my bug. Thank you so much for you answer and thank you for introducing me to react hooks.

Comment: Glad to hear that , can you please accept my answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 1):

> What is happening here? Why is my app not moving to ContactsTab() when the value of isLoggedIn successfully changes to true? How can I fix this?

Re-invoking app doesn't necessarily re-renders your screen. Your conditional invoking is not working properly because your render method is only called once, to fix it you need to change the state of your App component. You are just changing the state through your reducer but you are not listening to that change in your app component. You must listen to that change and upon that change, you need to set login state to true and then your component will perform rendering for you.

Read more about state [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/state).
Read more about how you can use redux to make your components listen to the change in state of your application [here](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getState).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my flaw i.e. not re-rendering. I've been wrapping all my Components inside App with connect() but can't seem to get my head around how I should wrap my whole App with connect.